# Load MP4 via StreamResource (Vaadin 23)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin23

I use **StreamResource** to upload several media types with Vaadin 23 (Vaadin doc https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/dynamic-content)

Uploading images (jpeg) and documents (pdf) works well with StreamResource but uploading videos (mp4) doesn't seem to work.

Uploading a local video (mp4) works fine with Chrome. So I think this problem is not related to the browser.

The video is less than 300Kb.

As you can see an HTML  tag is created but the video does not load.

[frontend - HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/has2T.png)

[frontend - video player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOpmq.png)

Has anyone ever successfully implemented video uploading with a recent Vaadin release?

Comment: What is your actual problem? The frontend code looks like a player and your subject says "load". But then you are talking about "uploading" half of the question?  Please be specific about what is not working. Also: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It actually sounds like you talk about "downloading". From server to web browser. If you can share the code you use to create the video player, that might help to solve the issue. Also, have a look at the network tab in browser. If the sample.mp4 is loaded there the problem might be the player configuration and not the file.